# Compute 1st value on multiple values on a checkbox

Tags: php

I was trying to make a COMPUTERIZED ORDERING SYSTEM. My problem is how can I compute the 1st value on my checkbox. The second value on the checkbox will be posted on the summary of orders.

Once I've check all those three, it will compute the total amount of the menu and to display the selected menu on the summary of orders. But I can't figure out how can I display the total amount.

Can anybody guide me how to compute the total on my 1st value on the checkbox?

```
<form method="post">
    <input name='ts[]' type='checkbox' value='40 |Tosilog'/> Tosilog
    <br>
    <input name='cs[]' type='checkbox' value='40 |Chiksilog'/>Chiksilog
    <br>
    <input name='ps[]' type='checkbox' value='45 |Porksilog'/>Porksilog
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="go" value= "Total">
</form>


<?php 
//tosilog
    $ts = $_POST['ts'];
    $value = explode("|",$ts[0]);
    echo $value[0];
    echo $value[1];


//chiksilog
    $cs = $_POST['cs'];
    $value = explode("|",$cs[0]);
    echo $value[0];
    echo $value[1];


//porksilog
    $ps = $_POST['ps'];
    $value = explode("|",$ps[0]);
    echo $value[0];
    echo $value[1];

?>
    <!-- compute for the 1st value on checkbox -->  
 <?php

            $ts=$_POST['ts[0]'];
            $cs=$_POST['cs[0]'];
            $ps=$_POST['ps[0]'];

?>


    <?php $compute = $ts[0] + $cs[0] + $ps[0];?>

    <?php echo "$compute " ; ?>
```

Comment: Change `echo "$compute " ;` into `echo $compute;` .

Comment: It still doesn't work. Still the total is 0. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting an array of checkbox elements, and they are numeric, you can use array_sum().  Not sure I understand your suggested structure, but I'll give you a code sample here based on the existing form structure.  Then I'll post another bit to try to make this simpler for you.  Executive summary: You do not need all the variables that are created by this form structure.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_user193.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$total  = 0;
$inputs = array();
$errors = array();
if (!empty($_POST))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['ts']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['ts'] as $ts)
        {
            $inputs[] = current(explode(' |', $ts));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Tosilog';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['cs']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['cs'] as $cs)
        {
            $inputs[] = current(explode(' |', $cs));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Chiksilog';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['ps']))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['ps'] as $ps)
        {
            $inputs[] = current(explode(' |', $ps));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = 'Porksilog';
    }

    // IF ERRORS
    if (!empty($errors))
    {
        echo 'UNABLE TO PRINT COMPLETE TOTAL.  MISSING: ' . implode(',', $errors);
    }
    $total = array_sum($inputs);
    if ($total) echo "<br/>TOTAL: $total <br/>" . PHP_EOL;

// END OF THE ACTION SCRIPT
}

// CREATE THE FORM
$form = <<<ENDFORM
<form method="post">
<input name='ts[]' type='checkbox' value='40 |Tosilog'/> Tosilog
<br>
<input name='cs[]' type='checkbox' value='40 |Chiksilog'/>Chiksilog
<br>
<input name='ps[]' type='checkbox' value='45 |Porksilog'/>Porksilog
<br>
<input type="submit" value= "Total">
</form>

ENDFORM;
echo $form;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll study this code first. But all the selected checkbox will also display the menu (chiksilog,tosilog,porksilog).
But it will not display what is missing. Once I've checked "porksilog" and "Tosilog", it will be displayed on the list of orders but it will not display that "chiksilog" is missing. But it solved my problem to display the total amount.

Comment: You can choose to leave that part out.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_miggy.php
This is probably more along the lines of the way I would do it.  The script knows what goes into the HTML and it knows exactly what to expect in the POST request.  It is easy to add or remove different inputs.  Often these kinds of inputs come from a data base table.

```
<?php // RAY_temp_miggy.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$total  = 0;

// EXPECTED INPUTS
$inputs = array
( 'Tosilog'   => 40
, 'Chiksilog' => 40
, 'Porksilog' => 45
)
;

if (!empty($_POST))
{
    // ACTIVATE THIS TO SEE WHAT WAS SUBMITTED
    // var_dump($_POST);

    // SUM OF THE ELEMENTS
    $total = array_sum($_POST);
    echo "TOTAL: $total";

    // SUM OF THE EXPECTED INPUTS
    $expect = array_sum($inputs);
    if ($total != $expect) echo " BUT THERE MAY BE INCOMPLETE INPUTS!";

// END OF THE ACTION SCRIPT
}

// CREATE THE FORM
$checkboxes = NULL;
foreach ($inputs as $name => $value)
{
    $checkboxes
    .= '<input name="'
    . $name
    . '" type="checkbox" value="'
    . $value
    . '" />'
    . $name
    . '<br/>'
    . PHP_EOL
    ;
}
$form = <<<ENDFORM
<form method="post">
$checkboxes
<input type="submit" value= "Total">
</form>
ENDFORM;
echo $form;
```